# rebuilding sybase clustered indexes monthly occasionally fails

Tags: indexing, sap-ase, rebuild

I am running into an issue dropping and recreating unique clustered indexes on some sybase databases. I have been unable to reproduce the issue in my test env.

The error that results when the concurrency issue arrises is as follows:

Cannot drop or modify partition descriptor database 'xxx' (43), object xx, index xx (0), partition 'xx' as it is in use. Please retry your command later. Total reference count '4'. Task reference count '2'.

I know an exclusive lock on a table or row from an open tran will not cause this, and I don't think anything the end-users could be doing would change the sort order of the data.

The data is a clustered round robin, and is a single partition table.

Please advise.

Comment: These databases are in Sybase ASE 15 FYI

Answer (score 1):

Could you use "reorg" instead - that'd have the same effect and should not be vulnerable to this?  But I'm not sure because I like you don't see how this happens - building the new clustered index shouldn't start until Sybase gets a table lock (it has to for a clustered,) so why does it appear something else is accessing?  (DBCCs, or something system level with locks on system catalogs maybe, so that although the index can build, something about updating the system catalogs fails?)

Before 15.0.3 esd 4 REORG causes other queries that try to access the table being reorged to fail, not to be blocked, which can be annoying.